# Apache not running on Debian 8

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, mysql

I'm trying to install a LAMPP Server on my freshly installed Debian distro, and I'm having issues running seeing the Apache site when I type localhost on my web browser. I've been doing research for the for a day now, and I still can't find what my problem is.

I have installed these packages `apt-get -y install apache2 mysql-server php5 php5-mysql php-pear php5-gd`

When I run `systemctl start apache2` and `systemctl start mysql` I get active and running like it should.

But when I try to check if apache is working by opening the browser and typing localhost or 127.0.0.1 the Apache Debian Default Page is not showing up. I have also tried installing XAMPP but when I start all the services only postgresql starts running.

The message I get when I run localhost on my browser:

> You don't have permission to access / on this server. Apache/2.4.10
>   (Debian) Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80

Anyone has any suggestion or knows a solution to this?

Comment: If you see that then Apache *is* running, which you can easily check with ps

Comment: @Rahul I have Apache/2.4.10 installed

Comment: can you please post content of `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file ?

Comment: @Rahul here's the apache2.conf file https://ghostbin.com/paste/xp7eh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace line number 153-157 with below code in your `apache2.conf`

```
<Directory />
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   allow from all
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then, do `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Comment: I'm still getting the same error 403 forbidden

Comment: have you checked apache logs ?

Comment: I just did, I think it might be because I removed the html folder inside www by accident, but I don't understand how is that related with apache because I think the folder was empty otherwise the errors I'm seeing in the log file is `access to / denied (filesystem path '/var/www/html') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path` or `Permission denied: [client ::1:45630] AH00529: /var/www/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/var/www/' is executable` I will  change the permissions for /var/www/ to chmod -R 755 /var/www/